# Big in-memory files and DB

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Edit:

I ended up using FileInputStream holding only indexes to locations I'm interested in instead of loading files to memory (updating the locations when needed).

This can be configured to use less memory (more memory accessing) if you hold less data each time or more memory (less memory accessing) if you hold more data.

You can adjust your buffers using the response times assuming you're looping through some code.

Although I'm sure this can be improved using non-blocking I\O, I didn't find it intuitive and I've resorted to using simpler things that I can control easily.

---

I have a project for the university that involves comparing big files for byte sequences.

In order to get this done fast I've decided to load all of the files into memory (files are about 500mb total) and compare them while storing the information in extracting in a small db (queries are not often done).

I've extended the "File" class to a new class "MappedFile" where each Mappedfile has a byte array (created when constructed) holding the file's bytes.

This is the entire MemFile class:

```
public class MemFile extends File{

private String md5;
private byte[] bytes;

public MemFile(String pathname) {
    super(pathname);
}

public byte[] getBytes(){
    if (this.bytes == null){
        this.bytes = FileUtils.getFileBytes(this);
    }
    return this.bytes;
}

public String getMD5(){
    if (this.md5 == null){
        this.md5 = MD5Generator.generate(this.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return this.md5;
    }
}
```

I'm holding a list of those and I'm extracting smaller arrays from the big byte arrays and then I look for them in the other files.

My problem is that I run out of memory fast when I only use a small subset of the 500mb files (I've started eclipse with 2gb of memory)

Is this a realistic approach to get this done or am I loading to many things into memory?

Is there an option to monitor virtual memory somehow?

- The DB is small and contains 4 entries when things slow down and are about to crash yet again, shattering my dreams of ever liking Java for such projects (it's mandatory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDK already has what you want: [`FileChannel#map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29).

What is more, it returns a `MappedByteBuffer`, which extends `ByteBuffer`, on which you can compare contents using `.equals()`.

Using Java 7, it is as easy as:

```
final FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("/path/to/file"),
    StandardOpenOption.READ);
final ByteBuffer buf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
```

(oh, and it implements `Closeable`, therefore `AutoCloseable`)

Comment: I'll try extending this class instead of the File class and let you know how it went. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to extend it, do you? At least, not from what I understand of your requirements.

Comment: I don't it's just more comfortable because I need to save file-related data instead of consistently asking for it again and again...

I saw extending it wouldn't be the cleanest of tasks, so I'll just integrate it on a test environment and see if it actually does what I need :)

Comment: Well, why don't you use composition? It is not as if you needed _all_ methods from `FileChannel`, do you?

Answer (score 2):

I would use memory mapped files.  These don't use much heap memory and can be faster to load.  They just use virtual memory so as long as you have 64-bit you can load thousands of these this much problem.

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(fileName).getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
```

You can keep doing this for all you files and it will use only a few KBs of the heap.  Note: this work for files up to 2 GB (larger than that you have to map in portions)

Comment: Why open a `FileInputStream` and not just a `RandomAccessFile`? (or just use `FileChannel.open()` since JDK7)

Comment: @fge I was being minimalist and making it all read only. RandomAccessFile can be made read only as well with an extra argument.

Comment: Fair enough... Or `StandardOpenOption.READ` with JDK7.